# Is it good to use rename object key in function parameters?

Tags: javascript, rename, destructuring, readability

Im quite new to Javascript. When im trying to learn the destructuring, i accidentially found out that i can rename the variable and use the old one as linking word to make the function easier to read (for me).

```
function getWords({ beginWith: character, from: text }) {
    return text.split(" ").filter(word => word.startsWith(character));
}

let msg = "Hello world.";
let words = getWords({ beginWith: "H", from: msg });
console.log(words);
```

However, I wonder if this has any side effects to the program or not and should I continue to use it?

Comment: Its al about how much readable function you want, you can always go ahead with renaming your destructured variables. No harms

Comment: Just write as you prefer.

Comment: Why not just define `function getWords(character, text) { ... }` and call `getWords("H", msg)`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Because JS don't have named function parameters. By passing an object as parameter, you can mimic the named function parameters features like other languages. You can even put the parameters in different order. You can also separate the construction of the parameter object and the actual function invoke to make the code cleaner when the parameters list get bigger. It is actually quite handy.

Comment: It’s up to taste; it does the right thing. I’d personally prefer `function getWords(opts) { const character = opts.beginWith; const text = opts.from; … }`.